# OrientDB - Problems with Clusters Concept

Tags: orientdb

I have got a problem with clusters in orient db. So I would like to be sure that my understanding of clusters is correct and then it would be great if you could help me with my problem.

### My understanding of Clusters

first I would like to ensure that I understand the concept of clusters correctly: For me a cluster is a subset of the data, one cluster can contain different classes and a single class can be contained in different clusters, is that correct ?

So for example I have the Data:

```
{"name": "john", "sports": "tennis", "gender": "male", "@class": "assistant"}
{"name": "susan", "sports": "hockey", "gender": "female", "@class": "assistant"}
{"name": "peter", "sports": "hockey", "gender": "male", "@class": "trainee"}
{"name": "mary", "sports": "tennis", "gender": "female", "@class": "trainee"}
```

and then I can have clusters like that:

```
cluster:Male {john, peter}
cluster:Tennis {john, mary}
```

Is this understanding of clusters in OrientDB correct?

### My Problem with Clusters

When inserting new Data to my database I want to add the data to a specific cluster. My Data is in json format. The cluster already exists. But after inserting with the following command the cluster is still empty. This occurs by using the java API as well as using the web interface.

```
INSERT INTO cluster:Test CONTENT {"name": "john", "@class": "assistant"}
```

The data itself is saved, when requesting:

```
SELECT FROM assistant
```

I do find the entry but the entry is not in the cluster:Test. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit 2014/03/26**

### My Usecase

I actually save Tweets in my database. I am searching Twitter by given keywords. My class model looks like:

- TwitterTweet
- TwitterUser
- Hashtag

(with a TwitterBaseClass above Tweet and User) and I have edges like that:

```
TwitterTweet --originalTweet--> TwitterTweet
TwitterTweet --postedBy--> TwitterUser
TwitterTweet --hasHashtag--> Hashtag
```

And I thought best practice to do efficient requests was to create a cluster for every keyword. So for example when I have the keywords "shark" and "dog" I get tweets for sharks and dogs and they are all stored in the same graph in different clusters.

---

Your help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance
Ludwig

*orient-db v. 1.7-rc1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next release 2.0 you cannot associate multiple clusters to a class, so in order to stay compatible with future releases, it's better to use class inheritance to split your records on multiple clusters.

**Edit 2014-10-08:**

This is not true anymore, with 2.0 you cannot store a record in any cluster, but it should be declared that host records of X class. So classes can have multiple clusters. We use this feature to manage distributed.

Comment: Can you give more specifics on how things will change in 2.0? Is there a roadmap posted anywhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the cluster "Test" to the class assistant via API or via SQL:

```
alter class assistant addcluster test
```

Comment: Hi Lvca, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I now add the cluster ids to the classes. Any other ideas?

Could you also answer my first question whether my understanding of clusters is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understand the problem at the first reading. This seems a bug when the CONTENT keyword overwrite the CLUSTER. Starting from 1.7x we discourage using different clusters for the same class because one of the future optimization would be removing this feature that a few developers use. Could you rather use 1 class -> 1 cluster and play with inheritance to have multiple class/clusters? Is it applicable to your use-case?

Comment: Hey Lvca, for me the concept of cluster - as I understand it - is really great and I would prefer to keep this feature.
I edited my question with more details for my use-case. I think it would work by creating a subclass everytime a new keyword is added but wouldn't be the nicer way to work with clusters?
----[[ Nothing the less my question seems to be answered that it isn't possible due to a bug and the mapping 1 class -> multiple clusters will be removed in a later version could you please write a new answer to summarize this so I can accept it? ]]----